# Add another image in image button with animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-image, android-imagebutton

I'm a rookie and noob but is it possible to add another image when an image button with animation is pressed?

Comment: you could change the image on the imagebutton by setting the onTouchListener, returning false in it, and then may be perform the action in the onclick listener

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Use the [`TransitionDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html), Luke!

```
mYourImageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
        layers[0] = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1);
        layers[1] = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image2);
        TransitionDrawable transition = new TransitionDrawable(layers);
        transition.setCrossFadeEnabled(true);
        mYourImageButton.setImageDrawable(transition);
        transition.startTransition(500 /*animation duration*/);
    }
});
```